# Call view from another view

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have a viewset with one of the views as:

```
@list_route(methods=["get"], url_path="special")
def special():
    pass
```

And I call this view from another view like:

```
view_fn = viewset.as_view({'get': 'list'})
response = view_fn(request)
```

But it does not call my `special` function which maps to `"/special/"`, instead it calls the function which maps to `"/"`. I guess I need to pass `url_path` somehow or get the view using view `name`? However, I'm not sure how to do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because you need to map that route with the action.

In its current form, you are mapping the default list action to the get method.

The following code should work:

```
view_fn = viewset.as_view({'get': 'special'})
```