# Handle many ViewSets with one URL in the Django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

What I want is to handle three ViewSet with one `URL` respect to the provided `request.data`.

Let's make it more clear by diving into code:

Here is my **router.py**

```py
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 et

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import viewsets

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'endpoint', viewsets.MyViewSet, 'my-viewset')

notification_urls = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Question1:**

Is it possible to handle three `ViewSet` with one URL?

**For example**, according to the data that has been sent, I want to select dynamically a different ViewSet instead of assigned `MyViewSet`.

```
---> /endpoint/ ---- | request.data['platform'] == 1 ----> ViewSet1 
                     | request.data['platform'] == 2 ----> ViewSet2
                     | request.data['platform'] == 3 ----> ViewSet3
```

and I know that I can call other ViewSet's methods in a `MyViewSet` something like this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858582/call-view-from-another-view) but this is really a messy one.

**Question2:**

Is it possible to dynamically pass extra params respect to the data that has been sent to a ViewSet?

**For example**, according to the data that has been sent, I want to pass an extra param into `MyViewSet`.

I know that I can do all this stuff in ViewSet `initial` method, Like this:

```py
def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.set_platform()
    super(NotificationViewSet, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But what I want is to handle this stuff during the `MyViewSet` instantiation.

**NOTE:** Maybe I can handle this by Writing a `Middleware` but if there are other options I would really be appreciated for sharing them with me.

Comment: If you implement this (somehow, ) it will be *tightly coupled code-base* which may lead difficulties in debugging. So, IMHO, this should be avoided

Comment: @ArakkalAbu thanks for warning me. I know this is against the rules and principles and best practices but this is some kind of business need and I have to find some way to implement it.  If that was a common need I think Django would recommend some ways to implement it. So If you were me what would you do to implement it?